# Loop through nested Object inside Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have the following JS to loop through the JSON data but when I am getting undefined because the `information` is an object inside the array and i'm unsure how to correct my code.

And also how would I wrap the output into separate divs?

#### JS

```
$.getJSON('js/test.json', function(data) {
  var importantInfo="<ul>";
  for (var i in data.hotelListing) {
    importantInfo+="<li>" + data.hotelListing[i].information.leaving + "</li>" + "<li>" + data.hotelListing[i].information.departureAirport + "</li>";
  }
  importantInfo+="</ul>";
  $(importantInfo).appendTo("#hotelInfo");
});
```

### JSON

```
{ "hotelListing" : [ 
  { "country" : "Austria",
    "information" : [ 
     { "airline" : "Thomson Airways",
       "leaving" : "21 Feb 2015 14:30"
     } ],
    "price" : "£499"
  },
  { "country" : "Austria",
    "information" : [ 
     { "airline" : "Thomson Airways",
       "leaving" : "21 Feb 2015 14:30"
     } ],
    "price" : "£549"
  }
] }
```

Comment: `information` appears to be an array, so try `information[0].leaving` etc.

Comment: ah, as simple as that! :)

Comment: @thg435 That's the answer

Comment: How can I seperate the output into seperate ul's rather than 1 list?

Comment: @DanMitchell: move the `ul` generation code to inside the loop.